# How to set nginx reverse proxy Apache-2.4(php5_module) with mod_remoteip

Tags: apache, nginx, proxy

`internet -> nginx -> apache-2.4`

Remote_Addr prints 127.1.1.0 instead of client ip. I have apache behaind nginx with the following settings:
nginx.conf:

```
location / {
        try_files $uri @apache;
        }

location @apache {
        internal;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        include proxy.conf;
        }

location ~ .*\.(php|php5)?$  {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        include proxy.conf;
        }
```

proxy.conf:

```
proxy_connect_timeout 300s;
proxy_send_timeout 900;
proxy_read_timeout 900;
proxy_buffer_size 32k;
proxy_buffers 4 64k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size 128k;
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_hide_header Vary;
proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding '';
proxy_set_header Referer $http_referer;
proxy_set_header Cookie $http_cookie;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

httpd.conf:

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:8080
Include conf/extra/httpd-remoteip.conf
```

httpd-remoteip.conf:

```
LoadModule remoteip_module modules/mod_remoteip.so
RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For
RemoteIPInternalProxy 127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sed -i "s@LogFormat \"%h %l@LogFormat \"%h %a %l@" /usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf